# Почему SuspendLayout не блокирует Refresh?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Я создаю контрол, со свойством от которого зависит его (контрола) внешний вид. Логично, что  его изменение должно вызывать `Refresh()`.

```
public uint BordersWidth
{
    get { return _bordersWidth; }
    set
    {
        _bordersWidth = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Теперь я хочу добавить его на форму и изменить свойство без перерисовки.

```
MyControl c = new MyControl();
c.SuspendLayout();
Controls.Add(c);
c.BorderWidth = 3;
c.ResumeLayout();
```

Но строка `c.BorderWidth = 3` вызывает `OnPaint` у моего контрола.

Почему так происходит? Разве `SuspendLayout()` не создан для того, чтобы приостанавливать  отрисовку на время изменения свойств? И как сделать так, чтобы она действительно приостанавливалась?

Comment: Возможно стоит вызывать не `Refresh()`, а `Invalidate()`?

Comment: @AlexeyM, `Invalidate()` делает так, чтобы контрол перерисовался при следующем WM_PAINT, но не посылает его. Будет немного странно заставлять человека, использующего контрол, вызывать `Update()` всякий раз после изменения свойства. А надеяться, что сразу после изменения свойства произойдёт событие, влекущее за собой WM_PAINT — тоже не лучший вариант.

Comment: Согласно [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx) `Invalidate()` посылает сообщение на перерисовку.
Invalidates a specific region of the control and *causes a paint message to be sent* to the control.

Comment: @AlexeyM, а теперь нажмите на любую из перегрузок метода :)

«Вызов метода `Invalidate` не приводит к принудительному выполнению синхронной перерисовки. Для ее выполнения следует вызвать метод Update после вызова метода `Invalidate`.»

`WM_PAIN` и «paint message» — разные вещи. Второе, полагаю, просто вызов события `Paint` на контроле, а первое — реальный вывод изображения формы на экран.

Comment: При инвалидации перерисовка действительно не происходит *синхронно*; WM_PAINT посылается только после обработки других сообщений. Что касается вопроса, то по-видимому SuspendLayout() не имеет отношения к перерисовке, а только к макету (докинг, размер, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как оказалось, `SuspendLayout` не блокирует перерисовку элементов управления, только приостанавливает логику макета (что полезно в TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel и при использовании свойств Anchor, Dock и др.).

Решение проблемы [существует](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778095/windows-forms-using-backgroundimage-slows-down-drawing-of-the-forms-controls):

```
public static class ControlHelper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;

    public static void SuspendDrawing(this Control target)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control target) { ResumeDrawing(target, true); }

    public static void ResumeDrawing(this Control target, bool redraw)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);

        if (redraw)
        {
            target.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это решает проблему. Хотя, конечно, в идеале хотелось бы подойти к ней со стороны контрола: получая `OnPaint`, узнавать, был ли вызван SuspendLayout, и перерисовываться только в противном случае.

Правда я не уверен, будет ли рады этому люди, ожидающие от `SuspendLayout` ровно того поведения, что описанное в MSDN.